# ASSEMBLY: issue with nested loop

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am working with nested loops in assembly. The desired output should be "ABCD" (new line) "EFGH" (new line) "HIJK" (new line) "LMNO" but currently I am not getting any output. The whole loop will execute but nothing will appear in the console.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
ALPHA byte "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z"
count byte 4 ; inner loop counter


.code
main proc

mov esi, OFFSET ALPHA
mov ecx, 4 ;outer loop counter
mov ebx, 0 ; inner counter
call part1
main endp

;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;part1 proc
;print 4x4 letter matric
;Receives EBX: arr address ECX: outer loop counter
;Returns EAX: full array
;-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
part1 PROC USES ebx ecx edx esi

L1:
    cmp ecx, 4 ; test outer loop count
    je next ; yes?
    call Crlf ; print new line
    inc ecx


L2:                                             ;inner loop
    cmp ebx, ecx ; 
    mov eax, [esi] ; mov next letter
    call WriteChar ; write it
    inc esi ; point to the next element
    inc ebx
    loop L2 ; loop

next: 
    call Crlf
    ret

part1 ENDP



end main
```

Comment: The `loop` instruction decrements ECX automatically and then compares it with 0 and branches back to the label if not zero. You use ECX for both the outter loop and the inner loop so it is conflicting. You want to use different registers for the counting of each loop.

Comment: You really don't need two loops to do this.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I wonder if that's the point of the assignment to do it with two loops. `working with nested loops in assembly` seems to point in that direction otherwise this code is easily done with one loop and doesn't even need `ALPHA db .....` for that matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does nothing what you describe.. let me step over single instruction with you, how the execution happens (this is not source code, but sequential write-down of instructions as they will be executed by CPU, with some minimal comments of important parts):

```
mov esi, OFFSET ALPHA
mov ecx, 4
mov ebx, 0
call part1
cmp ecx, 4
je next     ; jump is taken, because ecx == 4
call Crlf
... internal implementation of Crlf by Irvine32 ending with RET
ret         ; part1 "ret" returning into main
; there is no more code in main, so the CPU continues
; with next memory interpreting it as machine code
; with a bit of luck (no padding between ENDP/PROC, or NOPs)
; the "part1" code follows after main, so it will get executed
cmp ecx, 4
je next     ; jump is taken, because ecx == 4
call Crlf
... internal implementation of Crlf by Irvine32 ending with RET
ret         ; part1 "ret" returning out of your code completely
; in some environments that may work as clean exit from app
; in others that ret will go to whatever address is at stack and crash
```

You should be capable to verify this in your debugger. I wonder what made you think the *"The whole loop will execute"* and *"nothing will appear in the console"*, as clearly only minimal part of loop is being executed, and there should be two new lines in console appearing.

How to fix your code ... first add some kind of exit to the end of the main, if you are building win32 executables, then I think the standard way to exit Irvin32 programs is to use `ExitProcess` (check working examples of Irvine32 package). I think something like `invoke ExitProcess, 0` may work, `invoke` is some kind of predefined macro which will expand into `mov + call` instructions, but I don't have windows and/or Irvine32 to check myself.

Then make your mind, how you want actually to track the loops. For example put outer counter into `ecx` and inner counter into `ebx`, and because you know the size if fixed 4x4, do the count-down in `do { ..; --counter; } while (counter);` style, which fits assembly way of coding naturally (but it doesn't check counter validity at first iteration, so this is good style only for case where counter is always valid value).

Like for example:

```
part1 PROC USES eax ebx ecx esi
    mov  ecx, 4
outerLoop:
    mov  ebx, 4  ; reset inner counter (for every outer loop)
innerLoop:
    mov  al, [esi] ; load next letter
    call WriteChar
    inc  esi     ; point to next element
    dec  ebx     ; --innerCounter
    jnz  innerLoop
    call Crlf    ; print new line after 4 chars
    dec  ecx     ; --outerCounter
    jnz  outerLoop
    ret
part1 ENDP
```

Now this should produce in console something like this:

```
A,B,
C,D,
E,F,
G,H,
```

And that's because you did define the `ALPHA` as one long string, including the commas, etc... You probably did want something like

```
ALPHA byte 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P'
```

or the equivalent

```
ALPHA byte "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
```

both of them producing 16 bytes with values 65, 66, 67, ... (`'A' == 65`).

Also in your original code the:

```
mov eax, [esi] ; mov next letter
```

will load four bytes. The `WriteChar` does ignore the upper 24 bits of `eax` and will use only bottom 8 bits (the "`al`"), and you are incrementing `esi` only by one, so in the end this is harmless bug, but you should understand how it works. `mov al,[esi]` will fetch only 8 bits from memory, which is enough in this case, when working with characters.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am very inexperienced with assembly as you could see.